# Notation: set of marices with left/right inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, linear-transformations

We usually denote $GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ to the set of all invertible matrices of dimension $n \times n$ over field $\mathbb{K}$. But is there a notation for all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{K}$ posessing left/right inverses? Such notation may be useful when dealing with particular spaces.

For a simple example, consider $L_A(B) = AB$ an operation over a fixed matrix $A$. Consider the set $\{A: I_n \in \text{Im}(L_a) \}$; this is, the set of fixed matrices $A$ such that $I_n$ can be mapped via $L_A$. It is clear such set is the set of all matrices $A$ with a right inverse $A^{-1}$, where letting $B=A^{-1}$ results in the required mapping.

Comment: This is, perhaps, more relevant in the case of infinite dimensional matrices (for finite dimensional matrices, having a one-sided inverse implies the existence of a two-sided inverse).  If, say, you let $V$ be the vector space of sequences of real numbers, and let $S$ be the shift operator, given by $S(a_1, a_2, \cdots)=(0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)$,  then $S$ has a left inverse but no right inverse.

Comment: An $n \times n$ matrix has a left inverse iff it has an inverse iff it has a right inverse.